# Corrupted data in Ace Editor when using browser 'back' button in single page app

Tags: ace-editor, turbolinks

I'm using Ace Editor in a Rails app with [TurboLinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks). The editor is initialized each time a page is loaded (including when a page is loaded via the browser 'back' button):

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
});
```

When clicking a link to another page in the application, and then clicking the browser 'back' button, the editor field is corrupted. For example, if the data in the editor is:

```
toto
tata
```

The data (displayed in the textarea of the editor) after going to another page an coming back becomes:

```
12tototataXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**How to prevent this from happening in my application?**

Comment: which version of are you using, there was a similar bug in old version, but that is fixed in 1.2.8 and 1.2.9

Comment: @auser I'm using 1.2.9 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.9/ace.js

Comment: then something is restoring the dom element of the old editor before ace.edit call you can try setting value from js instead of relying on textContent

Comment: @auser Thank you for you help, I've worked around the problem by generating a new div for the editor at each page load (cf my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was the following (executed at each `turbolinks:load` event, including when user uses 'back' button):

1. remove the previous editor div (exists only when using 'back' button), with something like `$('#editor').remove()`
2. load the content from a hidden div that is never edited
3. add a new div for the editor, with the content to edit (something like `$('#foo').after(`${content}`)`
4. initialize the editor with `ace.edit("editor");`